# Selenium, Page Factory,Was not able to inherit a class with PageFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, page-factory

I was not able to inherit Menus Repository Class which has this constructor to another class named sub menus,

```
public MenusRepository(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}
```

when i inherit Eclipse shows this Message as
Implicit super constructor SubMenusRepository() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor, and advice's to add

```
public WasteStrorageRepository(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

I am quite confused on how it works, I am new to Selenium and PageFactory, Need clarification on how does this work and how to handle, I have Webelement on both the class. So MenusRepository Class will be inherited by SubMenus Class followed by the last test case Class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a base page object class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePageObject {

    WebDriver driver;

    public BasePageObject(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

}
```

And here's an example of a page object that extends the base page object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class CalculatorPage extends BasePageObject {

    public CalculatorPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "userid")
    WebElement userID;

    public void setUserID(String text) {
        userID.sendKeys(text);
    }

}
```

The page class **extends** the base class, and the constructor calls the base class to initialize, passing the driver parameter.